# iOS NSDate and NSDateFormatter behavior

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

So, I have a String with the format YYMMDDHHMMSS, and I'm trying (hard) to get a proper NSDate object from it.

This is my code:

```
NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[format setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
[format setDateFormat:@"yyMMddHHmmss"];
NSDate *date = [format dateFromString:@"140904123421"];
```

NSLog(@"DATE: %@", date);

And I'm getting weird times like this:

```
DATE: 2014-09-04 17:04:21 +0000
```

I've checked this [table](http://waracle.net/iphone-nsdateformatter-date-formatting-table/) and my formatters seem right, I also tried removing the locale, but I still got wrong dates. So, is it possible to get back the right time?

Thanks.

Comment: When you log an NSDate object, you always get it in that format, with the time shown in GMT.

Comment: Your are right. I converted it back to NSString and got the original string. The problem is, I need to save this to a database (SQLite) and the queries are working with wrong times. Any suggestions?

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm expecting my database to work with this time: 2014-09-04 12:34:21, not 2014-09-04 17:04:21

Comment: When your parse a time string you need to have the date formatter set to the time zone represented by the string.  When you format a date you need to have the date formatter set to the timezone in which you want the resulting string to be represented.  The time stored in an NSDate object should *always* be UTC.

Comment: The time zone in Venezuela is GMT-04:30, which means that 2014-09-04 12:34:21 in your time *is*  2014-09-04 17:04:21 GMT, so the output is correct.

Comment: If you want to keep the time zone complexities out of your application scope and if you plan to operate only in one time zone, move all calculations to GMT. Either by specifying 'Z' as `[format setDateFormat:@"yyMMddHHmmssZ"]; [format dateFromString:@"140904123421Z"]` or by setting time zone as `    NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]; [format setTimeZone:timeZone];`. Having said, I want t reiterate you date is correct and all date operation would be correct with date what you currently get on the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments on your question, your `NSDate` is correct; `NSDate` always stores its time in `GMT`. By default, when `NSDateFormatter` parses your date it converts it from your local time zone to `GMT` so that what's stored in the resulting `NSDate` object is consistent (it's actually more nuanced than that, but you can think of it that way). Since your time zone is `GMT-04:30` that means it's going to add 4 hours and 30 minutes to your time, making `2014-09-04 12:34:21 GMT-4:30` = `2014-09-04 17:04:21 GMT` (as @MartinR pointed out).

From your comments, it sounds like you need to store this date in your database in the format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`, **in local time**. The easiest way to do that is to simply use a second `NSDateFormatter`:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatOut = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatOut setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *dateString = [formatOut stringFromDate: date];
```

Since `NSDateFormatter` will use your local time zone by default, that should "convert" `date` from `GMT` back to `GMT-4:30` and set `dateString` to `2014-09-04 12:32:21`.

---

All that being said, **storing a date in your local time zone is almost always a bad idea**. Time zones are tricky things, so it's best to always store and do any calculations on your date in `GMT`/`UTC`, then only convert it to local time when you're displaying it to your user. This will save you a lot of pain if someone outside your time zone accesses your data, your time zone rules change (happens more often than you might think), you need to pass your date to some external service/app, etc.

Comment: Never store times in local time.  It may seem like a good idea to start with, but will backfire.  Or, at the very least, make sure the stored date includes the timezone identifier.

Comment: @HotLicks very true. I added a note to that affect to the answer.